# Prometheus metrics by tenant id in a flask web api

Tags: flask, prometheus, grafana

I have a Flask webapi which serves a SaaS and I want to monitor its usage with Prometheus and Grafana.

It is easy to setup the monitoring to check the different endpoints (nr of calls, avg execution time, etc...). However, I would like to separate not only by endpoint, but also by tenantId, so I can see what each tenant is doing. I have added a label which is the tenant id and it works perfectly and I can see everything in my Grafana dashboard.

My doubt is that, as the # of tenants increases, the /metrics endpoint will also start growing and growing, as each metric will be duplicated by all the tenants. Is it the correct way to do it? I am thinking that maybe there is a better solution besides scaling up prometheus and grafana servers.

Comment: Generally, it is not deemed a good idea to have metrics with ever-increasing cardinality of labelsets: you will lose not only performance on exposing/scraping step, but also on storage and performance of aggregation (while querying). Consider using something with less cardinality if possible, for example locality of user.

Comment: Additionally, metrics in general is a wrong place for tracing your user actions. They are for performance related use. If you want detailed tracing what, when and how specific user does something , consider using appropriate tracing or logging solution.

Comment: P.S. as this question doesn't really have correct answer, it is opinion based. And those are not allowed here, and generally not well received.